# How to turn a "specific function type" into a function pointer type genericaly?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, coercion

In rust when a name denotes a function, its type is actually specific to that function:

```
fn f(){}
```

The type of `f` is not `fn()` but `fn() {f}`. This actually causing me serious trouble in production code.

I would like to know if there is a way that turns any "specific function type" into a function pointer type without the need to repeat what is the function type. The function would map

- `fn() {f}` to `fn()`
- `fn(i32) {g}` to `fn(i32)`
- ...

Let's see a simplified example of the issue:

```
trait X{}

impl<R> X for fn()->R {
}
impl<R,A> X for fn(A)->R {
}

fn f(){}
fn g(i32){}
fn h(f32){}

fn test<T:X>(_:T){}

fn main() {
    test(f); // Compiler Error
    test(g); // Compiler Error
    test(h); // Compiler Error

    // All work around implies that library users
    // have to write the function type
    let a: fn() = f;
    test(a); 
    let b: fn(i32) = g;
    test(b); 
    let c: fn(f32) = h;
    test(h); 

    test(f as fn()); 
    test(g as fn(i32)); 
    test(h as fn(f32)); 

    // I would like something as:
    test(to_fn_pointer(f)); 
    test(to_fn_pointer(g)); 
    test(to_fn_pointer(h)); 
}
```

---

## About the real case:

I have written a tiny layer on the java native interface to ensure type safety.

When the library written in "native" code is bound to java code manually we have to call [RegisterNative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#registernatives).

This function takes as an argument a string representation of the signature of the java function and a pointer to a (rust) function.

To ensure that the function pointer passed to that function and the java function signature matches, I have written a trait that generates directly the "signature" from the function type.

What is bellow is a simplification but it exposes the trouble:

```
struct NativeMethod{
   signature: CString,
   function: *const c_void,
}
trait Signature {
  fn signature() -> String;
}
impl<R:Signature> Signature for fn()-> {
  fn signature() -> CString {
    "()" + R::signature()
  }
}
impl<R,A> Signature for fn(A) {
  fn signature() -> CString {
    "(" + A::signature() + ")" + R::signature
  }
}
// ... for functions of x arguments
impl Signature for f32 {
  fn signature() -> String {
    "F".to_owned()
  }
}
//... 

pub fn declare_native_method<T: Signature + IsFnPointer>(function: T) -> {
  NativeMethod {
   signature: T::signature(),
   ptr: function as * const c_void,
  } 
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot call `declare_native_method(function)` because i must explicitly convert `afunction` to a function pointer. The code is thus verbose and needs duplication of the function type.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to generically coerce function item types to their respective function pointer types.  Perhaps if you could explain a little more about your `X` trait, and in particular how it is used within the `test` function, there may be A Better Way of approaching this problem?

Comment: @eggyal Ok I have just done it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way, at least as far as I know.

Instead, I would create a (probably proc-)macro that will verify the signature. It can take the Java signature and the Rust function pointer, convert the Java signature to Rust signature and call `register("javaSig", rustFn as RustSig)`. This will generate a compile-time error if the signature is wrong.